# Not able to escape characters in my regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to handle backslash so that I am able to convert \t(single) to \t (double \) but this code /regex doesn't work. Could you help me with where I am doing it wrong?

```
var a = {"value": '[{"skill":"\tAgile,Scrum", "exp": 2}, {"skill": "Coding", "exp": 10 }]'};


a.value = a.value.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"); //handle special char

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string doesn't have any literal backslashes in it. For example, `\tAgile,Scrum` is equivalent to a *tab character* concatenated with `Agile,Scrum`. There are no backslashes in the string, so `/\\/g`, which matches a literal backslash, will not match anything.

You'll have to match the interpreted character(s) instead, like `\t`, and replace them with a literal backslash followed by a literal `t`:

```js
var a = {"value": '[{"skill":"\tAgile,Scrum", "exp": 2}, {"skill": "Coding", "exp": 10 }]'};

a.value = a.value.replace(/\t/g, "\\t"); //handle special char

console.log(a);
```

You'll have to write out each character you want to replace. If you have a bunch of them (eg `\t` `\r` `\n` `\v` etc) you might find it more concise to start with an object mapping the characters to their replacement values and constructing the pattern from that, eg:

```
const replacements = {
  '\t': '\\t',
  '\r': '\\r',
  // etc
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `\t` has already been parsed and handled as a `\t` character (a tabletop I believe). Look for a `\t`:

```js
var a = {
  "value": '[{"skill":"\tAgile,Scrum", "exp": 2}, {"skill": "Coding", "exp": 10 }]'
};

a.value = a.value.replace(/\t/g, "\\t"); //handle special char

console.log(a);
```

Or you could use a backticked string:

```js
var a = {
  "value": `[{"skill":"\tAgile,Scrum", "exp": 2}, {"skill": "Coding", "exp": 10 }]`
};

console.log(a);
```